# iPhone: how to communicate with external devices?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, physics

Hey, I would like to understand how iOS can communicate with external devices (example: http://www.icelsius.com). I know I could use OSC but if I understand this you need a network so.. devices communicate over wifi. I don't know where to start. I would like to make a voltmeter, you would plug a cable into the iPhone and I would read signals with the iOS.
thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to apply to Apple's [MFi program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). If and when they accept you, they will provide you with documentation on how to communicate over the dock connector.

Comment: of course you don't need to join the "Made for iPod" program to make devices for android. And prepare for not getting into MFi, they are quite picky. But when you are accepted you'll have to add ~$5 to your BOM because you need a authentication chip, and apple wants a license fee for each produced device.

Comment: I'm looking for the documentation how to build devices... how to read from cable...